# How do you replace patterns with conditional patterns in R?

Tags: r, regex

I am loading PDF data into R and trying to conjoin string values as part of the cleaning process... I'm having a problem with replacing regex values.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is this:

```
string <- c("New York 58.1 60.5 Long Island")

string <- str_replace_all("[[:alpha:]][[:space:]][[:alpha:]]","[[:alpha:]]_[[:alpha:]]",string)
```

So the replacement value would depend on the specific pattern being replaced.

Trying to get:

```
string
"New_York 58.1 60.5 Long_Island"
```

But I'm getting:

```
"Ne[[:alpha:]]_[[:alpha:]]ork 58.1 60.5 Lon[[:alpha:]]_[[:alpha:]]sland"
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this? Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
str_replace_all(string, "([[:alpha:]])([[:space:]])([[:alpha:]])", "\\1_\\3")
# "New_York 58.1 60.5 Long_Island"
```

```
gsub("([[:alpha:]])([[:space:]])([[:alpha:]])", "\\1_\\3", string)
# "New_York 58.1 60.5 Long_Island"
```

`\\1` refers to the first regex chunk (`([[:alpha:]])`) of the pattern that you found, `\\2` to the second chunk and so on.

Comment: Thanks! I've seen this notation before but didn't fully follow until now, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookarounds:

```r
library(stringr)
string <- c("New York 58.1 60.5 Long Island")
str_replace_all(string, "(?<=\\p{L})\\s(?=\\p{L})", "_")
## => [1] "New_York 58.1 60.5 Long_Island"
```

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/dwKUq0) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pby6Ix/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=\p{L})` - a positive lookbehind requiring a letter immediately to the left of the current location
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?=\p{L})` - a positive lookahead requiring a letter immediately to the right of the current location.

A variation of the same solution is

```r
str_replace_all(string, "(\\p{L})\\s(?=\\p{L})", "\\1_") ## Capturing group/backreference used to restore captured text
str_replace_all(string, "(?<=\\p{L})\\s+(?=\\p{L})", "_") ## If there are more than 1 whitespace between letters
```

A base R version is

```r
gsub("(?<=\\p{L})\\s+(?=\\p{L})", "_", string, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't have much experience with lookarounds but this is a more eloquent method than mine, very helpful!

Comment: @QuasiNovice Just FYI, lookarounds allow matching overlapping strings, so my solution turns `a b c` into `a_b_c` while the other solution without lookarounds turns it into `a_b c`. See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/bcSBMa).